# Writing loops to save files in R

Tags: r, write.table

I have a very simple question, as an R newb.  I want to run a code to execute a function, and subsequently save the resulting files.  Here's what I have so far:

```
for (m in 1:30){
    drought.slice <- rotate(drought.array[m,,])
    drought.vec <- as.vector(drought.slice)
    length(drought.vec)
    drought.df01 <- data.frame(cbind(lonlat, drought.vec))
    names(drought.df01) <- c("lon", "lat", paste(dname,as.character(m), sep = "_"))
    head(na.omit(drought.df01))

    csvfile <- "cru_drought_[m].csv"
    write.table(na.omit(drought.df01), csvfile, row.names = FALSE, sep = ",")

}
```

However, when I do this, it does not save files 1 to 30 in the folder. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: You need to use `paste` or `sprintf` to put the variable in the string file name. The string `"text"` is always `"text"`. If I set `x = 5`, it doesn't become `"te5t"`. Your string `"cru_drought_[m].csv"` is always `"cru_drought_[m].csv"`, no matter what value `m` has.

Answer (score 3):

```
csvfile<-paste0("cru_drought_",m,".csv")
```

consider also `write.csv`